# Calculating the current of an infinitely long plane?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electric-current, gauss-law

I stumbled across this question and it doesn't seem to have any kind of solution...or am I just not understanding this correctly?

**Question**
There is a sheet that is infinitely long in length but has a width, $w$. It lies across the $xy$ plane and carries a current density $J = J_0$ Amp/m. What is the current flowing in the sheet?

Does this question make any sense? If it is infinitely long and the current depends on how long the sheet is, how would it be possible to calculate the area of an infinitely long sheet to find the current flowing through it?

Comment: *"and the current depends on how **long** the sheet is"* - think about that more carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current depends on the width of the sheet.

Think of an infinitely long wire with a current I in it. The current does not depend on the length of the wire. Current is a measure of electrons per second flowing past a point.

For a sheet, think of a roll of conductive paper towels. The goal is to find how many electrons per second are flowing past the line between two towels.

If the current in a strip 1 cm wide is 1 Amp, and the paper towels are 20 cm wide, the total current is 20 Amp.